# Bloquear Prints

Tags: java, while, do-while

O programa deverá:

- receber um numero de 4 dígitos,
- ordenar de forma crescente e guardar,
- ordenar de forma decrescente e guardar.
- Subtrair o de forma crescente ao decrescente e guardar para que volte a executar o processo desde inicio até que a subtração seja igual a 6174.

Não posso utilizar metodos da classe arrays.

Não percebo como devo bloquear os prints umas vez que se utilizar um While o programa entra em loop infinito.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradecia

Exemplo:

> 1: N=2016 A=6210 B=0126 A-B=6084
>
> 2: N=6084 A=8640 B=0468 A-B=8172
>
> 3: N=8172 A=8721 B=1278 A-B=7443
>
> 4: N=7443 A=7443 B=3447 A-B=3996
>
> 5: N=3996 A=9963 B=3699 A-B=6264
>
> 6: N=6264 A=6642 B=2466 A-B=4176
>
> 7: N=4176 A=7641 B=1467 A-B=6174
>
> 8: N=6174 A=7641 B=1467 A-B=6174

O código realizado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kaprekar {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("");
        int n0 = in.nextInt();

        do{
        int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0, n4=0;

        n1=(n0/1000);
        n2=((n0-n1*1000)/100);
        n3=((n0-n1*1000-n2*100)/10);
        n4=n0-n1*1000-n2*100-n3*10;

        int dmaior=n1, dmedio1=n1, dmedio2=n1, dmenor=n1;

        if(n2>n1&&n2>n3&&n2>n4){
            dmaior=n2;
            if(n3>n4&&n3>n1)
                dmedio1=n3;
            if(n4>n3&&n4>n1)
                dmedio1=n4;
            if(n3>n4&&n3<n1||n3>n1&&n3<n4)
                dmedio2=n3;
            if(n4>n3&&n4<n1||n4>n1&&n4<n3)
                dmedio2=n4;
            if(n3<n4&&n3<n1)
                dmenor=n3;
            if(n4<n3&&n4<n1)
                dmenor=n4;  
        }
        else if(n3>n1&&n3>n2&&n3>n4){
            dmaior=n3;
            if(n2>n4&&n2>n1)
                dmedio1=n2;
            if(n4>n2&&n4>n1)
                dmedio1=n4;
            if(n2>n4&&n2<n1||n2>n1&&n2<n4)
                dmedio2=n2;
            if(n4>n2&&n4<n1||n4>n1&&n4<n2)
                dmedio2=n4;
            if(n2<n4&&n2<n1)
                dmenor=n2;
            if(n4<n2&&n4<n1)
                dmenor=n4;  
        }
        else if(n4>n1&&n4>n2&&n4>n3){
            dmaior=n4;
            if(n3>n2&&n3>n1)
                dmedio1=n3;
            if(n2>n3&&n2>n1)
                dmedio1=n2;
            if(n3>n2&&n3<n1||n3>n1&&n3<n2)
                dmedio2=n3;
            if(n2>n3&&n2<n1||n2>n1&&n2<n3)
                dmedio2=n2;
            if(n3<n2&&n3<n1)
                dmenor=n3;
            if(n2<n3&&n2<n1)
                dmenor=n2;  
        }

        int dr=dmaior*1000+dmedio1*100+dmedio2*10+dmenor;
        int cmaior=dmenor;
        int cmedio1=dmedio2;
        int cmedio2=dmedio1;
        int cmenor=dmaior;
        int cr=cmaior*1000+cmedio1*100+cmedio2*10+cmenor;
        int rr=dr-cr;

        System.out.println("N="+n0+" A="+cr+" B="+dr+" A-B="+rr);

        n0=rr;

        }
        while (n0!=6174);

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54219/discussion-on-question-by-bfr-bloquear-prints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema real é que o sua ordenação não considera todas as possibilidades. Por exemplo, você não tem um `if` verificando se o `n1` é o maior número. Eu te aconselharia a separar essa parte da ordenação em um método separado e não consigo pensar no momento em um método que não ficaria muito grande comparando número por número, então simplifiquei utilizando um `array`. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kaprekar {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("");
    int n0 = in.nextInt();

    do {
      int cr = ordenar(n0);
      int dr = inverter(cr);
      int rr = dr - cr;

      System.out.println("N=" + n0 + " A=" + cr + " B=" + dr + " A-B=" + rr);

      n0 = rr;

    } while (n0 != 6174);

  }

  private static int ordenar(int numero) {
    int[] listaNumero;

    listaNumero = inteiroParaArray(numero);
    Arrays.sort(listaNumero);

    return arrayParaInt(listaNumero);
  }

  private static int inverter(int numero) {
    StringBuilder construtor;
    String invertido;
    String texto;

    texto = String.format("%04d", numero); // Completa com 0
    construtor = new StringBuilder(texto);
    invertido = construtor.reverse().toString();

    return Integer.parseInt(invertido);
  }

  private static int[] inteiroParaArray(int numero) {
    String numeroString = String.valueOf(numero);
    int[] resultado = new int[numeroString.length()];
    int indice;

    for (indice = 0; indice < numeroString.length(); indice++) {
      resultado[indice] = numeroString.charAt(indice) - '0';
    }

    return resultado;
  }

  private static int arrayParaInt(int[] numeros) {
    StringBuilder numeroString = new StringBuilder();
    int resultado;

    for (int numero : numeros) {
      numeroString.append(numero);
    }

    resultado = Integer.parseInt(numeroString.toString());

    return resultado;
  }
}
```

*Uma observação é que a saída que você colocou na sua pergunta produz o resultado inverso já que **A** deveria ser **crescente**.*

Reescrevi seu código para que ficasse um pouco mais organizado, utilizando uma nomenclatura um pouco mais clara e também dividindo em métodos. Também alterei para que a lógica não estivesse no método `main`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kaprekar {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kaprekar kaprekar = new Kaprekar();

    kaprekar.ler();
  }

  public void ler() {
    Scanner entrada;
    String lido;

    entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    /* Utilizei nextLine para que você possar validar se realmente é um inteiro
     * ou não, afinal se o usuário digitar algo que não seja número será retornado
     * um erro ilegível */
    lido = entrada.nextLine();
    try {
      this.validar(lido);

      while (!lido.equals("6174")) {
        int milhar;
        int centena;
        int dezena;
        int unidade;
        int[] listaCrescente;
        int[] listaDecrescente;
        int crescente;
        int decrescente;
        int subtracao;

        // Pega os valores numéricos para serem utilizados na ordenação de acordo com a posição
        milhar = Character.getNumericValue(lido.charAt(0));
        centena = Character.getNumericValue(lido.charAt(1));
        dezena = Character.getNumericValue(lido.charAt(2));
        unidade = Character.getNumericValue(lido.charAt(3));

        listaCrescente = new int[]{milhar, centena, dezena, unidade};
        // Ordena o array de forma crescente
        Arrays.sort(listaCrescente);
        listaDecrescente = inverter(listaCrescente);

        crescente = this.arrayParaInt(listaCrescente);
        decrescente = this.arrayParaInt(listaDecrescente);
        subtracao = decrescente - crescente;

        System.out.println("N=" + lido
                + " A=" + this.mostrarFormatado(crescente)
                + " B=" + this.mostrarFormatado(decrescente)
                + " A-B=" + this.mostrarFormatado(subtracao));
        lido = String.valueOf(subtracao);
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.out.println("O valor lido não é um número");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Valida o que foi incluído pelo usuário
   *
   * @param lido
   * @throws Exception
   */
  private void validar(String lido) throws Exception {
    Integer.parseInt(lido); // Retornará um NumberFormatException que será tratado no método que chamou

    if (lido.length() != 4) {
      throw new Exception("O valor lido " + lido + " não tem 4 caracteres");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Inverte o array de inteiro
   *
   * @param base
   * @return Um novo array invertido
   */
  private int[] inverter(int[] base) {
    int[] resultado = new int[base.length];
    int indiceBase;
    int indiceRetorno;

    indiceRetorno = 0;

    // Percorre o array de base de trás pra frente
    for (indiceBase = (base.length - 1); indiceBase >= 0; indiceBase--) {
      resultado[indiceRetorno] = base[indiceBase];
      indiceRetorno++;
    }

    return resultado;
  }

  /**
   * Transforma um array de inteiro um novo inteiro
   *
   * @param numeros
   * @return Um inteiro com as posições do array
   */
  private int arrayParaInt(int[] numeros) {
    StringBuilder numeroString = new StringBuilder();
    int resultado;

    for (int numero : numeros) {
      numeroString.append(numero);
    }

    resultado = Integer.parseInt(numeroString.toString());

    return resultado;
  }

  /**
   * Mostra um inteiro formatado com 4 dígitos
   *
   * @param numero
   * @return
   */
  private String mostrarFormatado(int numero) {
    return String.format("%04d", numero);
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Caso não queira usar `arrays` como foi adicionado na pergunta você pode mudar o método `ordenar` para o seguinte e aplica-lo no primeiro exemplo, removendo os métodos que ficarão sem uso:

```
private static int ordenar(int numero) {
  int a = numero / 1000;
  int b = ((numero - a * 1000) / 100);
  int c = ((numero - a * 1000 - b * 100) / 10);
  int d = numero - a * 1000 - b * 100-c * 10;
  int tmp;

  if (a > b) { tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }
  if (c > d) { tmp = c; c = d; d = tmp; }
  if (a > c) { tmp = a; a = c; c = tmp; }
  if (b > d) { tmp = b; b = d; d = tmp; }
  if (b > c) { tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp; }

  return a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d;
}
```

Seu código final sem usar `Integer.parseInt` ficaria assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kaprekar {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("");
    int n0 = in.nextInt();
    int ultimoResultado;

    do {
      int cr = ordenar(n0);
      int dr = inverter(cr);
      int rr = dr - cr;

      System.out.println("N=" + n0 + " A=" + dr + " B=" + cr + " A-B=" + rr);
      ultimoResultado = n0;
      n0 = rr;
    } while (n0 != ultimoResultado);

  }

  private static int ordenar(int numero) {
    int a = numero / 1000;
    int b = ((numero - a * 1000) / 100);
    int c = ((numero - a * 1000 - b * 100) / 10);
    int d = numero - a * 1000 - b * 100-c * 10;
    int tmp;

    if (a > b) { tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }
    if (c > d) { tmp = c; c = d; d = tmp; }
    if (a > c) { tmp = a; a = c; c = tmp; }
    if (b > d) { tmp = b; b = d; d = tmp; }
    if (b > c) { tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp; }

    return a * 1000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + d;
  }

  private static int inverter(int numero) {
    int a = numero / 1000;
    int b = ((numero - a * 1000) / 100);
    int c = ((numero - a * 1000 - b * 100) / 10);
    int d = numero - a * 1000 - b * 100-c * 10;

    return d * 1000 + c * 100 + b * 10 + a;
  }
}
```